# Upload Zip file from ios7 app

Tags: ios7, upload, zip, afnetworking-2

I try upload to soap based webservice zip file, I want use AFNetworking 2.0

my code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];


[manager POST:urlString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    //
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:zipPath] name:@"FILE" fileName:@"DocumentsZippedLogs.zip" mimeType:@"application/zip"];
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"succes");
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"fail %@", error);
}];
```

and my error:

```
Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: unsupported media type (415)" UserInfo=0x8edd240 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=my url here, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8d9a830> { URL: http://10.233.208.10:8072/Service.svc } { status code: 415, headers {
"Content-Length" = 0;
Date = "Fri, 14 Mar 2014 15:18:50 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
```

} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unsupported media type (415)}

Could u tell me what is wrong ?

Thanks for your help
Best Tomek :)

Comment: Can you try setting "application/octet-stream" fır MimeType?

Comment: I tried and it nothing help :/